# How do I set a Ext Grid Filter Default?

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

I have a working sort-able grid using the ext 3.4 grid filter plugin.  I would like to default the active column to filter true values.  User who needs the inactive records could remove the filter.  How do I specify a default filter column and value?

Thanks in advance!

```
colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    defaults: {
        sortable: true
        // How do I specify a default filter value
        //
        // Only show active records unless the user changes the filter...
    },
    columns: [{
        dataIndex:'f_uid',
        id:'f_uid',
        header:'ID',
        hidden:true
    }, {
        dataIndex:'f_name',
        id:'f_name',
        header:'Name',
    }, {
        xtype:'booleancolumn',
        dataIndex:'f_active',
        id:'f_active',
        header:'Active',
        filterable:true,
        trueText:'Active',
        falseText:'Inactive'
    }]
```

Comment: The answer was in the Filter.js source code.  The filter object within the column definition can be used to configure the default behavior.  I am not allowed to answer yet.

Comment: filter: { value:1, active:true }

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is an old question but it took me a while to find a solution, therefore I thought I would share.

1) The filter can be set using the value property in the filter.

```
filter: {
          type: 'LIST',
          value: ['VALUE TO FILTER']
        }
```

2) In order to initially filter the data use the filterBy() method in the store. This could be defined in the onRender event handler.

```
this.getStore().load({
    scope:this,
    callback: function() {
        // filter the store 
        this.getStore().filterBy(function(record, id) {
            // true will display the record, false will not
            return record.data.DATA_TO_FILTER == 'VALUE TO FILTER ';
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer was in the Filter.js source code.  The filter object within the column definition can be used to configure the default behavior.

```
}, {
        xtype:'booleancolumn',
        dataIndex:'f_active',
        id:'f_active',
        header:'Active',
        trueText:'Active',
        falseText:'Inactive',
        filterable:true,
        filter: {
            value:1,    // 0 is false, 1 is true
            active:true // turn on the filter
        }
}
```

Comment: I have set a filter as you write above, however it is not active when you load the page. after if you refresh grid it activates filter and show results. do you know how I make it active for the first grid load.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem and I found that @John's answer is right, I can make it work with the sample http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html, for the grid-filter-local.js, just add the code like:

```
grid.getStore().load({
    scope:this,
    callback: function() {
        // filter the store 
        grid.getStore().filterBy(function(record, id) {
            // true will display the record, false will not
            return record.data.size === 'small';
        });
    }
});
```

before the original code *store.load()*, and wipe off the *store.load()*.
Then it will only show the record with size equals 'small' at the first load of the web page. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a universal helper class that allows you to set any default values in column definition.
https://gist.github.com/Eccenux/ea7332159d5c54823ad7

This should work with both remote and static stores. Note that this also works with filterbar plugin.

So your column item is something like:

```
{
    header: 'Filename',
    dataIndex: 'fileName',
    filter: {
        type: 'string',
        // filename that starts with current year
        value: Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y'),
        active:true
    }
},
```

And then in your window component you just add something like:

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.callParent();

    // apply default filters from grid to store
    var grid = this.down('grid');
    var defaultFilters = Ext.create('Ext.ux.grid.DefaultFilters');
    defaultFilters.apply(grid);
},
```